# How to create community and collection hierarchy in xml format for dspace xmlui

Tags: xml, dspace

How to create community and collection hierarchy list in xml format for dspace xmlui.
I need to create a xml of community and colection list hierarchy.

Comment: What research have you done so far? This will help the community better answer your question

Comment: I presume you are attempting to run https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+Community+and+Collection+Hierarchy.  The AIP export tools may meet your needs: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/AIP+Backup+and+Restore

Comment: I donot need to backup and restore. I just need to generate community and collection hierarchy xml so that i may used to export to another website

Answer (score 0):

This is also somewhat covered in terrywb's comment, but the facility you can use is the "Structure Importer".

The documentation features an example XML file that makes it clear how you need to put it together:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+Community+and+Collection+Hierarchy

Copying this example here:

```
<import_structure>
        <community>
                <name>Community Name</name>
                <description>Descriptive text</description>
                <intro>Introductory text</intro>
                <copyright>Special copyright notice</copyright>
                <sidebar>Sidebar text</sidebar>
                <community>
                   <name>Sub Community Name</name>
                   <community> ...[ad infinitum]...
                   </community>
                </community>
                <collection>
                   <name>Collection Name</name>
                   <description>Descriptive text</description>
                   <intro>Introductory text</intro>
                   <copyright>Special copyright notice</copyright>
                   <sidebar>Sidebar text</sidebar>
                   <license>Special licence</license>
                   <provenance>Provenance information</provenance>
                </collection>
         </community>
</import_structure>
```

Comment: The following is only for the import but i need to export the community and  collection hierarchy