# DSpace 6.3 Is there a way export the Community / Collection hierarchy?

Tags: database, export, dspace

We are migrating from DSpace to external host, BePress.  I've found how to export the items in each collection along with the metadata for each collection.

What isn't apparent, is how do you export the hierarchy?

For example, I can export the items for handle (10106/26887) and then the metadata for that collection.  On the export of the metadata, the output includes the name of the Collection, Publications.

The hierarchy is actually:

Department of Curriculum and Instruction -> Daniel H. Robinson, Ph.D. -> Publications

```
[root@rc bin]# /ebs/uta-dspace/bin/dspace metadata-export -f /tmp/uta-dspace/26887.csv -i 10106/26887
**Exporting collection 'Publications' (10106/26887)**
[root@rc bin]# /ebs/uta-dspace/bin/dspace export -t COLLECTION -i 10106/26887 -d /tmp/uta-dspace/ -n 1
Exporting from collection: 10106/26887
Beginning export
Exporting item to 1
Exporting Item 7b9d1b23-3163-47fa-8524-650d224f6d5c, handle 10106/26888 to /tmp/uta-dspace/1
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/1/dublin_core.xml
Exporting item to 2
Exporting Item 86ee2a6d-d4bb-40eb-b879-d79538c527f1, handle 10106/26926 to /tmp/uta-dspace/2
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/2/dublin_core.xml
Exporting item to 3
Exporting Item 8b3ad0b8-4dff-466d-aafe-9dec615888d5, handle 10106/26915 to /tmp/uta-dspace/3
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/3/dublin_core.xml
Exporting item to 4
Exporting Item 978e9492-db70-47c3-91bf-f0b4cbaaf9c9, handle 10106/26916 to /tmp/uta-dspace/4
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/4/dublin_core.xml
Exporting item to 5
Exporting Item bd6089cc-dcbe-444e-a116-e86535aa654d, handle 10106/26930 to /tmp/uta-dspace/5
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/5/dublin_core.xml
Exporting item to 6
Exporting Item c2ac97ea-e333-45a3-8cac-48c8fec2b7d3, handle 10106/26928 to /tmp/uta-dspace/6
Attempting to create file /tmp/uta-dspace/6/dublin_core.xml
```

How does one export the hierarchy "Department of Curriculum and Instruction -> Daniel H. Robinson, Ph.D. -> Publications"?  I've looked through the dspace database but can't anywhere where the actual names are stored; guessing they're all hashed.

And yes, I understand the DSpace 6.3 is no longer officially support and we should upgrade.

Comment: I found this question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531932/how-to-create-community-and-collection-hierarchy-in-xml-format-for-dspace-xmlui) but its for import.  I need to export this heirarchy.